# Display file upload images in webform view

Tags: views, webforms

I have a webform where users can upload images. For easier administration, I created a view of these submissions.

The default behavior of the field is to display as a link. However, I would like to preview the images by displaying them in an image tag.

I looked at the field re-write behavior, but it only gives me the entire href.

How can I display image field values as images in a webform view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This can not be done with webform module alone.**
All you need to do is get help of 2 extra modules.

1. [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity)
2. [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

Further you need to do following things.

1. Download and enable both of the modules and clear the cache.
2. Webform is storing file, not only image. I am assuming here you are only uploading image files, you can further get idea to show any type of file there. So go to Image File Type Display: `admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display` and set the preview/image style. Or if you do not want to change settings for default view mode of the file, download another module [Entity View Mode](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode). Go to it's configuration and create specific display and set image style accordingly in file display settings.
3. Create a view of files, it should be a block. and there add contextual filter for the fid and add field "`File: Rendered`". You can set file view mode by this field. For your convenience I'm exporting the view below, you just need to import this.

```
    $view = new view();
    $view->name = 'file_view';
    $view->description = '';
    $view->tag = 'default';
    $view->base_table = 'file_managed';
    $view->human_name = 'File view';
    $view->core = 7;
    $view->api_version = '3.0';
    $view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

    /* Display: Master */
    $handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
    $handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'File view';
    $handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
    $handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
    $handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
    $handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
    $handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
    $handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
    $handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
    $handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
    $handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
    /* Field: File: Name */
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['id'] = 'filename';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['table'] = 'file_managed';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['field'] = 'filename';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['label'] = '';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
    /* Field: File: Rendered */
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['id'] = 'rendered';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['table'] = 'file_managed';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['field'] = 'rendered';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['label'] = '';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
    /* Contextual filter: File: File ID */
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['id'] = 'fid';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['table'] = 'file_managed';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['field'] = 'fid';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['default_action'] = 'default';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['default_argument_type'] = 'node';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

    /* Display: Single File View */
    $handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Single File View', 'block');
```

4. Now in your main view (where you are showing submissions). Add a new relationship for `Webform submissions: Data`. You'll need to set the nid for the webform here and select the image component.
5. Add new field to the view `submission data: Value (raw)`. This will give you the file_id for the associated file. Exclude it from display.
6. Add another field `Global: View`. Select the view you imported and the block display. In contextual filter set [!data] from replacement patterns. It was the raw value of the field which you excluded from the display. And Here you go, save the view and rock :). Thanks for asking such good question. Still if you face any problem during this tutorial, ask me.